# Retrieving specific number of rows based on sum of row number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

After reading an experimenting I decided I need to ask:

I am trying to retrieve a specific number of rows from a table based on the sum of the row number: This is a basic table with two columns: `CusID, CusName`.

I started by numbering each row to 1 so that I can use a SUM of the row number, or so I thought.

```
WITH Example AS
(
    SELECT  
       *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CusID ORDER BY CusID) AS RowNumber
    FROM 
       MySchema.MyTable
)
```

I am not sure how to move beyond here. I tried using the `HAVING` clause but obviously that would not work. I could also use TOP or Percent.

But I would like to retrieve the rows based on the sum of row number.

What's the way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.So you can not use Aggregate function inside the row_number I think it could better than use all function after your with like this

```
 WITH Example AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CusID ORDER BY CusID) AS RowNumber
FROM MySchema.MyTable
)
select cusid,cusname,sum(rownumber) from example 
group by Cusid,Cusname
having .....
```

Comment: Not sure I explained this right. How do I get 5 records/rows from the table by summing the row number? If I say Having SUM(RowNumber) = 5. That does work. Because obviously each row is a one. - Thank you for responding.

I am looking for something that's equivalent to TOP but instead will add the row number and return them based on a value. Like return 10 rows by Summing the row number to equals 10. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to be clear again: I want to say return 10 rows or 5 rows. So maybe SUM is the wrong way??

Comment: I misunderstand and confuse for your question.if you could explain your request with some data in excel obviously more than user can answer your question.